# Forgot pass code and want to know if my recent videos will be safe if I restore from iTunes???? Help please!

Tags: iphone, video, restore, photo-stream, security

I forgot my pass code on my iphone 5. I know I can restore from iTunes but what about the videos on my phone?  We recently took a trip and I have uploaded all the photos but not the videos,:(. Do they back up when my phone backs up to the cloud? I also haven't backed them up to my computer yet. I really don't want to loose all these videos of my kids!!!! I have an iPad Air also but I know videos don't stream right?  Please help me if possible thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you connect your iPhone to iTunes you can do a backup, you should be able to do this even without the pin. Then just restore last backup and you're fine!

There is either a big "backup now" button or you can right click on the name of your iPhone and then select backup. Depends from the iTunes version.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to perform a backup, even if you have forgotten your passcode, however you will be limited to a computer you have synced with in past.

According to this [Apple support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1212?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) you should be able to get one last backup in before restoring.

Good Luck